# Как вывести результат выполнения скрипта LUA в TMemo?

Tags: delphi, lua

Есть задача по реализации простого редактора LUA используя Delphi. Надо выполнить скрипт, при нажатии кнопки и вывести результат выполнения этого скрипта в Memo.

Как получать (считывать) ответы из выполнения скрипта для их вывода в Memo?
Версия LUA не имеет значения.

Доступ к средствам LUA использую обвертку verysimple-lua-2-0 для Lua5.3.0.dll

Comment: Ну, Вы бы уточнили - какой компонент для LUA используется...

Comment: я перейду на любой, если буду понимать как реализовать эту задачу:-), на данный момент как рабочий инструмент использую данное решение http://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/02/18/verysimple-lua-2-0-a-cross-platform-lua-5-3-0-wrapper-for-delphi-xe5-xe7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей библиотеке у класса TVerySimpleLua есть событие OnPrint.
Добавьте обработчик и выводите в Memo

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что надо!!!